# How to set Text Block Alignment to "Top" in Visio as Default

Tags: microsoft-visio

Is there a way to set the default Text Block Alignment in Visio 2007 to top so that every shape I create will be set to Top instead of Middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another good application of the Visio **Styles** feature.

First, (enable the **Drawing Explorer**)[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2011/06/03/finding-the-style-explorer-in-visio-2007-and-visio-2010.aspx].

One the **Drawing Explorer** is enabled, right-click on the **Normal** style and select **Define Styles...**

[image: Drawing Explorer]

Then the **Define Styles** dialog will appear. In the **Change** section click the** Text** button.

[image: Define Styles Dialog]

The **Text** Dialog will appear. Select the **Text Block** tab and under** Alignment** select **Top**.

[image: Text Dialog]

Click **OK** and then **Apply**.

Now any shape you draw will  have by-default its text aligned at the top. For shapes that you Drop from a stencil, these dropped shapes will typically be set to a different style specific to their stencil. Just drop a shape, and repeat the above procedure for the default style used in the stencil.

**ProTip**: Create a custom toolbar and add the Style button to it, so that you can easily see what style is set on a selected shape.

Answer (score 1):

You could select all the shapes after creating your document and run a macro similar to what is listed here:

http://www.visguy.com/2007/11/07/text-to-the-bottom-of-the-shape/

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I'm really looking for something that sets it as the default for all shapes when they are created on the page.